# Visual Studio 2013 - Replace All Button gone (not just off screen)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

**I am unable to perform multi-file text search and replace (in Visual Studio).**

In the past, when I opened the "Replace in Files" dialog, there were 4 buttons in the lower right. One of the bottom two buttons allowed me to "Replace All".

The two lower buttons (including "Replace All") are no longer present.

I believe this occurred after I changed some Windows settings so that I could use menus without the Magnifier.

It is not just a matter of the buttons being off-screen because the window is too large (although it is too large - they would be off-screen, if they were present).

I can drag the window and see the bottom, even though the top is then off-screen (I use AltWindowDrag, allowing me to hold the ALT key, and drag by any part of the window, not just the title bar).

The two lower buttons are not present. I'm unable to resize the window - when I try, nothing happens, or the window repositions so that I can see the title bar, but can no longer see the bottom.

The two buttons that are still present (Find Next and Replace) don't have keyboard shortcuts, so I presume that Replace All doesn't either. Nor can I select either of those two buttons using Tab, so probably can't select an "invisible" "Replace All" button that way.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use Find and Replace by pressing Ctrl+H and to Replace All just use Alt+A.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works perfectly.

Comment: I recommend that you close this question so that it doesn't appear in the Unanswered section anymore.

Comment: Please stop dragging your feet. A full 12 seconds passed between making my post, and receiving your reply. :).  Seriously, that's the fastest reply I've ever gotten. It would have been fast if we had been in a chat dialog.

Comment: Looking for button to close it......

Comment: If you can't find it, write an answer and accept it. Or I'll convert my comment to an answer, then you can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to "close the question". The ONLY option I see, is the ability to comment. I can't add an answer.

Comment: Now you can accept my answer, and the question will be closed :)

Comment: There is now an "answer your question" button available. However, I see no way to accept your answer. I've refreshed the URL several times.

Comment: There should be a check mark beside my answer. Click it. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks. It turned green, so I presume that means "answer accepted as good".

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Any more problems on stackoverflow, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Looks like I need that tour. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Find and Replace by pressing Ctrl+H and to Replace All just use Alt+A.